# Kafka - commiting offset before consumer is shut down on app stop + commiting offset from the past

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, offset

Ive got a spring-kafka consumer set up. It is consuming avro data from the topic, maps the values and writes a CSV files. I manually commit the offset once the file is either of 25000 records long or each 5 minutes - whichever comes first.

A problem occurs when we restart the app because of patching/releases.

I have a method like this:

```
   @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        LOGGER.info("shutting down");
        writeCsv(true); 
        acknowledgment.acknowledge(); // this normally commits the current offset
        LOGGER.info("package commited: " + acknowledgment.toString());
        LOGGER.info("shutting down completed");
    }
```

So ive added some loggers there and this is how the log looks:

```
08:05:47  INFO KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - myManualConsumer: Consumer stopped
08:05:47  INFO CsvWriter - shutting down
08:05:47  INFO CsvWriter - created file: FEEDBACK1630476236079.csv
08:05:47  INFO CsvWriter - package commited: Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = feedback-topic, partition = 1, leaderEpoch = 17, offset = 544, CreateTime = 1630415419703, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 156)
08:05:47  INFO CsvWriter - shutting down completed
```

The offset is never commited since the consumer stops working before the acknowledge() method is called. There are no erros in the log and we are getting duplicates after the app is started again.

1. Is there a way to call a method before the consumer is shut down?

Also one more question:

i want to set up a filter on consumer like this:

```
if(event.getValue().equals("GOOD") {
addCsvRecord(event) 
} else {
acknowledgement.acknowledge() //to let it read next event
```

Lets say i got offset 100 - and GOOD event comes, i am adding it to the csv file, the file waits for more records and offset is not commited yet.
A BAD event comes up next, it is filtered out and offset 101 is commited immiedietely.
Then the file reaches its timeout and is about to close and call

```
acknowlegdment.acknowledge()
```

on offset 100.

2. What can possibly happen there? Can the previous offset be commited?

Comment: Check if your acknowledgement mode is set to `AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`

Comment: It is set to MANUAL. Does setting this to MANUAL_IMMEDIATE solve problem #1?

MANUAL - acks are queued and the offsets committed in one operation when all the results from the last poll have been processed.

MANUAL_IMMEDIATE - the offset is committed immediately (sync or async) as long as the ack is performed on the listener thread.

Seems like a solution !

Comment: Yes, it might. try and check

Comment: It did not really help. I am going to commit offset after each record to get over this problem. Thanks for help though! :)

Comment: `@PreDestroy` is too late in the context lifecyle; the container is already stopped by then; see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@PreDestroy` is too late in the context lifecyle - the containers have already been stopped by then.

Implement `SmartLifecycle` and do the acknowledgment in `stop()`.

For your second question, just don't commit the bad offset; you will still get the next record(s).

Kafka maintains two pointers `position` and `committed`. They are related, but independent for a running application.