# Committing latest processed Kafka offset from SmartLifeCycle stop() correctly when application is stopping

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

[Kafka - commiting offset before consumer is shut down on app stop + commiting offset from the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69008922/kafka-commiting-offset-before-consumer-is-shut-down-on-app-stop-commiting-of)

The answer here suggests to commit from the stop() method of SmartLifeCycle.

I am using spring-kafka and @KafkaListener annotation. How can I get the Acknowledgement object from listener in SmartLifeCycle stop() method correctly? What I did for now is to create a global variable for consumer and then assign it with the consumer obtained inside from listener. Then in stop() I had called:

```
 consumer.commitSync(processedOffsets)
```

It is working as expected. But I don't think it is correct!

Also committing inside stop() method raises a warning:

> "Kafka consumer is not safe for Multithread processing"

since it is running on shutdown thread rather than Kafka listener thread.

May I know the correct way to commit latest offset from stop() method?

Answer (score 0):

You should not interact with the consumer directly.

The container will automatically commit any acknowledged offsets when it is stopped. So stop the container.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is I am using manual_immediate acknowledge mode to handle commits manually to reduce duplicates and commit events which were processed but could not be acknowledged. If I stop container, won't it remain at last offset on scenario the stored variable with offset got updated after processing and then application stopped before acknowledging. Hence resulting in an extra duplicate record.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "processed but could not be acknowledged". Maybe edit the question to show some code? But, nonetheless, you can't access the consumer from a different thread, in any scenario.

Comment: Once my Kafka listener receive the message I am performing some transformations on it (this is meant as processing). Then I will consider that offset as committed and save the offset somewhere (for now in a static variable). Then I will acknowledge record manually rather than leaving it to Kafka. In this case, suppose application stopped before acknowledging but after saving offset in variable I wanted to commit latest offsets from variable in SmartLifeCycle stop() method. I believe you also meant the same in that answer in the link other than the manually acknowledging part.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense; the application can't stop until the listener exits anyway.